# Text annotation tool dataset

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for a dataset containing text annotation tools, with as many following fields as possible:

- name of the tool
- date of first release
- date of last release
- programming language
- license
- price
- which natural language processing task(s) does the tool target
- free-text description
- university or company developing it
- source of funding
- research groups that used the tool
- research articles that used the tool
- natural language(s) that the tool uses for its interface

Examples of text annotation tool:

- [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/)
- [gate](https://gate.ac.uk/)

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out [Dataturks.com](https://dataturks.com). It was released in 2018, fully online and supports multi-user collaboration.

Features supported: **Image bounding box, Polygon bounding box, NER, NLP annotation, tagging entities in documents etc.**